# How do I delete a survey question that has a blank title?

Tags: survey-list

A new survey question was accidently added which has a blank title.

It appears in the list of questions but without a link to get into the editor.

How to delete it?

Comment: How did you create a question without title? My SharePoint wont let me do that!

Comment: Apparently, the user entered a number of blanks and it was accepted!!

Comment: So then technically the Title isn't actually blank.. it just has whitespace. ;)

Comment: I hope you reprimanded the user for being a smart-ass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK Although the list of questions did not display a link to edit the empty question, there is actually a link in the source. I just showed the source code, copied out the link, pasted it into the browser address. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dataview/excel?

Answer (score 0):

The title field is part of the item content type which is the parent content type of all SharePoint content types. That means you cant remove it but you can make it an optional field. What happened is that the user entered that survey and left out the title what you then could do is look up the id of that result and navigate to the results display page of that specif result id and you can do as you please "Delete"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I resolved it thru SharePoint Designer.
Go the `SharePoint Designer > List and Libraries > List(Survey Name) > Customization > Edit list columns >Select the blank question > right click > Delete.`

This resolved my problem.